# django integer model field with float form input

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I am working with a django model which stores currency values as integers. i.e. GBP22.35 gets stored as 2235.

When that model gets rendered as a form, I need to be able to associate a widget with that integer field so can be edited as though it were a float value (i.e. to two decimal places - 22.35) and is validated as such. form.save() then needs to save the native integer value to the db.

I've tried creating a custom FormField/Widget pair which involves dividing by 100 in the widgets render and multiplying back up in the fields to_python method, but it all goes awry if there is an error on the form. The widget keeps re-dividing the value.

I realise this could be avoided by using float/decimal model fields but that is not an option in this case.

Is this something people have done before? Any pointers?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `FloatField` ?? Ok, I see you don't have that option.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Storing currency data in a `FloatField` is [never an acceptable option](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: Using firebird as a db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a subclass of `IntegerField` that handles that conversion behind the scenes:

```
import decimal
from django.db import models
from django.core import exceptions
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CentsField(models.IntegerField):
    empty_strings_allowed = False
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _("'%(value)s' value must be a decimal number."),
    }
    description = _("Fixed-point number")

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None or isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
            return value
        try:
            if isinstance(value, int):
                return decimal.Decimal(value) / 100
            else:
                return decimal.Decimal(value)
        except decimal.InvalidOperation:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid'],
                code='invalid',
                params={'value': value},
            )

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return int(value * 100)
```

Should behave as `DecimalField` in your Django code, but as `IntegerField` in your database.

*Update: simpler implementation derived from `IntegerField` instead of `DecimalField`; added validation as implemented in `DecimalField.to_python`*